# How to change the css of VideoJS Player without restarting it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video.js

I have a videoJS player, I want to change the border radius based on the value of playerView. When I add the boolean variable as a dependency to the useEffect, It keeps restarting the player. When I remove it from the dependency array, it doesnt work. I want to change the css of the player without restarting it.

Below is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

export const VideoJS = (props) => {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const {options, onReady, switch, playerView} = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {

    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {

      // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode. 
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");
      videoElement.style.width = '100%'; // Set your desired width
      videoElement.style.height = '100%';
      videoElement.style.borderTopRightRadius = playerView? '0px':'20px';
      videoElement.style.borderTopLeftRadius = playerView ? '0px':'20px';
      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        onReady && onReady(player);
        player.on("timeupdate", () => {
          switch(player.currentTime());
        });
      });

    // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
    // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;
      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <div ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoJS;
```

And this is how I call it from my component.

```
<VideoJS
   options={generateVideoJsOptions(fileLocations[index], index !== 0)}
   onReady={(player) => handlePlayerReady(player, index)}
   switch={index === 0 ? switch : () => { }}
   playerView={playerView}
/>
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!